# Nextcloud and Thunderbird: Finishing tasks is really slow

Tags: thunderbird, nextcloud, caldav

I have a problem with my setup with Nextcloud and Thunderbird. I use CalDAV for calendar and tasks. Finishing a task takes up to 5 seconds and finishing multiple tasks at once results in a sync error. So when I want to finish my daily tasks it takes a lot of time and nerves.

My nextcloud instance runs locally on a raspi with no other users and with a LAN connection to my computer.

The raspi does nothing else as the cloud. My setup uses nginx, mariadb and redis.

Does anyone have an idea how to speed up the process?

Thanks so much in advance :)

PS: Version numbers for sake of completion:

Nextcloud: 15.0.5
Thunderbird: 60.6.1

should not be so relevant - I had the problem with older versions as well.

Comment: Check your server load. Nextcloud is not exactly fast/lightweight and Pi is not exactly fast. Otherwise test with a different CalDAV client and consider filling a Nextcloud bug report.

Comment: What Nextcloud client version? Consider adding to your post screenshots of the errors and logs.

Comment: @harrymc There should not be a Nextcloud client involved if the protocol is CalDAV. More specifically, *Thunderbird is the client* and Nextcloud is operating in purely a server role.

Comment: How big is the database? Too many emails may stress the db. `mariadb`+`Pi`+Nextcloud  altogether seem no to be so delighted by big or huge databases...